# Laravel 5.7 Cannot Declare Class Name in Use

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.7, laravel-controller

I'm trying to make multiple auth in my website; I'd like one view for the log as a user and another to log as a client. I have a users table, and I create a client table with code instead of mail and mtpass instead of a password.

**ClientLoginController**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as CltController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ClientLoginController extends CltController
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:client');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('client.auth.login');
    }

    public function showClientLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.loginClient', ['url' => 'client']);
    }

    public function clientLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'Code' => 'required|email',
            'Mtpass' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['Code' => $request->Code, 'Mtpass' => $request->Mtpass], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/main');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('Code', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:client')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showClientLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.loginClient', ['url' => 'client']);
    }

    public function clientLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'Code' => 'required|email',
            'Mtpass' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('client')->attempt(['Code' => $request->Code, 'Mtpass' => $request->Mtpass], $request->get('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->intended('/main');
        }

        return back()->withInput($request->only('Code', 'remember'));
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        $role_id = auth()->user()->role_id;

        if (auth()->check()) {
            switch ($role_id) {
                case 1:
                    return 'admin/profil';
                case 2:
                    return 'client/profil';
                case 3:
                    return 'agent/profil';
            }
        }

        return '/main';
    }
}
```

I can't figure it out how to fix the following error.

> Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\ClientLoginController, because the name is already in use

Can someone help me to fix and understand what is happening? Thank you all!

Comment: Is the ClientLoginController located in App\Http\Controllers ?

Comment: sorry i didn't wrote it, yes it is: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: There is another class "ClientLoginController" in this namespace. It could be that you have another file (named completely different) that has the same classname by mistake (common copy-paste mistake)

Comment: Login should be done with one controller.  Use some type of role to determine what to send back/show the logged in user.  I recommend using Gates/Polices

Comment: Stormhammer thank you for your response unfortunately i looked up deep inside my little code and there aren't another class name as the same...

Comment: Thanks brad too, i'm new to laravel since 3 months, i'm building my website alone step by step and by now it's hard to applie those best practises, hopefully soon

Comment: Thank you Karl Hill for your lesson of grammar!!! i'm french can you believe that??

Comment: Its hard to determine what might be causing the issue from what you posted. Try changing the name from `ClientLoginController` to maybe `UserLoginController`. The `name already in use` error occurs when a class is required or included more than once. Are you maybe loading the class manually using a `require` or `include` statement?

Comment: Thank you Adam, unfortunately no matter the name i choose, this error occured and i'm not require or include neither! i keep trying! thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and

can not solved by composer dump-autoload

then use this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385832/308578